# How to store the file path and file name into the database(mysql) using jsp servlet code?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have uploaded the folders to the server folder so now i want to store the file path and file name into the Mysql database, and display stored files from database to the front end in a tree structured way.

Here is code pls help

```html
page.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.net.*"%>
<HTML>
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="uploadandstore.jsp" METHOD=POST>
<center>
<table border="0" bgcolor=#ccFDDEE>
<tr>
<center><td colspan="2" align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE</B><center></td>
</tr>
<br><br><br>
<tr><td colspan="" align="center"> </td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Choose the file</b></td>
<td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td></tr>


<table>
</center>
</FORM>
</HTML>
```

```html
uploadandstore.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.sql.*"%>
<%

String saveFile="";
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
saveFile="C:/UploadedFiles/"+saveFile;
File f = new File(saveFile);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
%>
   
     <%
 
   }
%>
    <a href="viewFiles.jsp">View Files</a>
```

```html
viewFiles.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<html>
<table>

<%
File f = new File("C:/UploadedFiles/");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
            String name=files[i].getName();
            String path=files[i].getPath();
            
%>
<tr><td><%=name%></td><td><a href="download.jsp?f=<%=path%>">Download</a></td></tr>
     <%
        }
%>
</table>
</html>
```

```html
download.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.net.*"%>

<%!
public static String getMimeType(String fileUrl)
    throws java.io.IOException, MalformedURLException 
  {
    String type = null;
    URL u = new URL(fileUrl);
    URLConnection uc = null;
    uc = u.openConnection();
    type = uc.getContentType();
    return type;
  }

%>
 <%
    String file=request.getParameter("f");
    File f = new File (file);
    String filename=f.getName();
    String type=getMimeType("file:"+file);

    response.setContentType (type);
    response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"");

    String name = f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf("/") ,f.getName().length());
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
        ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();

        int bit = 256;
        int i = 0;
            try {
                    while ((bit) >= 0) {
                        bit = in.read();
                        outs.write(bit);
                    }
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                        outs.flush();
                    outs.close();
                    in.close(); 

        %>
```

Comment: What do you mean ?
you can't if you got a file by request !

Comment: pls can you edit my code or provide any code. thenk you

Comment: I don't know what do you mean ! so how can i give you a suggestion ?

Comment: do you already had a file in your server ?

Comment: yes i had a file in server.

Comment: do you want to save the file path which you created

Comment: yes i want save the path file into the database and file name. after storing into the database. those file must fetch to the front end

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Based on the comment

```
String filePath=f.getAbsolutePath(); // this will get the file path
try(Connection conn=getDBConnection();// here it will open a DB connection
PreparedStatement peparedState=conn.preparStatement("INSERT INTO PATHS SET path=?")// Query
peparedState.setString(1,filePath); // setting the variable corresponding to '?' 
preparedState.executeUpdate()); // executeQuery
```